# Sitecore Media images with path "/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/-/media" throwing 500 error

Tags: media-library, mediaurls

We can see `500` errors in the log files for the media files. Those files are having urls with  `/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/` in it.

Why the media Urls uploaded in Sitecore are getting created with the above path? Does anyone have any idea why it throws an exception?

Comment: Have you checked for which media files it is using these url as prefix because the root path for content item images is `/sitecore/media library` in cms? Once we have listed then we can analyze its cause.

Comment: Not able to identify at which places or for which images, this prefix is getting added. We can just see error in the log files.

Comment: Add the snapshot of log file for better clarity.